# Mod_rewrite redirecting a url issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm working on a small PHP script. I used mod_rewrite to redirect some URLs but I found a problem when I wanted to convert `http://localhost/mobile/g-phones-1.html?pn=2` to `http://localhost/mobile/phones.php?id=1&pn=2`.

I used this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-phones-([^-]*)\.html?pn=([^-]*)$
phones.php?id=$2&pn=$3 [L]
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See anything in the rewrite log? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I cant see anything, thank you for your help !

Comment: `RewriteRule ^mobile\/g\-phones\-(\d+)\.html\?pn\=(\d+)$ mobile/phones.php?id=$1&pn=$2 [L]`. I posted this as a comment because you're supposed to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`, but this method somehow works too. I adjusted paths for root domain.

Comment: @It is not working ! Please remember that g is a variable also! and i dont want to include mobile directory in the rewrite !

Comment: Duh, more exclamation marks! Then `RewriteRule ^\g\-phones\-(\d+)\.html\?pn\=(\d+)$ phones.php?id=$1&pn=$2 [L]`

Comment: @DeDee Please try to understand i told you g is a variable and you still keep making it in the code also for the mobile directory it is still there

Comment: I just escaped `\g`, do you even regex bro? And no, mobile directory is not there.

Comment: @DeDee Why escaping it ? it is avariable it may g as it may k as it may any letter it sàould be rewrited

Comment: In another example `.` is _any non-white-space character_ and `\.` is a dot. Get it?

Comment: @DeDee You code didn't work :( However thank you so muc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-phones-([^-]*)\.html$ phones.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` flag is used to append current query string (`pn=2`) to rewritten URL.
BTW, you can't test your query string in rewrite rule, you have to use :

```
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}   ^REGEXP$
```